# How to reveal all errors on initial page load with redux form?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have a redux form where enableReinitialize is set to true. After my initial values are filled in, my field validation error message doesn't display the until that field is marked as touched. Is there a way to touch all the field on page load so that my error messages occur immediate instead of only on click of that field or on click of submit?

I tried touchOnChange and that didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mark the fields as touched. You can just put the code to display the errors in the componentDidMount() function so that they just always render when the component is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

redux-form touch action can be used here. i have done this before, it works.

[redux-form touch](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/actioncreators.md/)